# Is it possible to retrieve the value of custom fields defined in a plugin in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields

I want to modify a WordPress plugin which does not work properly.
That is,

```
function append_query_string($url) {
  global $post;
  if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'inm_la_title_url', true) ) {
    if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'inm_la_new', true) ) {
      $link = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'inm_la_title_url', true) . '" target="_blank';
    } else {
      $link = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'inm_la_title_url', true);
    }
  } else {
    $link = $url;
  }
  return $link;
}
```

The plugin file contains the above code. But it has an issue and I want to use the custom field "inm_la_new" defined within this plugin.

I tried to use the following code in the index.php file:

```
<?php
if ( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'inm_la_new', true) ) { 
  echo '" target="_blank'; 
} 
?>
```

However, it does not work in the index.php file. I think it's because the "inm_la_new" field is defined within the plugin not within the theme's functions file. Is there a way to retrieve the custom field defined in a plugin not in the theme's functions file?

Thank you.

Comment: i don't know the answer, but what happens if you var_dump($GLOBALS); ? do you find anything called inm_la_new  anywhere?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. "inm_la_new" is a custom field which is added to a post by a plugin. It provides a checkbox which determines whether the links of the post title & thumbnail will be opened in a new window (target="_blank").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure it will help, but try to use this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/, i think it will help you use the custom field from the other plugin.

Or you could just follow the docs step by step https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

If the custom field has data in wordpress db as meta data (like the code from the plugin you posted), you should be able to use it from anywhere.